# Submitting iOS app for iPad-1 with iOS 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, app-store, ios5.1

> EDIT: My answer is provided below

I was developing an educational app **which I was targeting specifically for iPad-1 devices**, because I think schools can take advantage on these 'old' devices.

However I'm afraid that nowadays it is not possible to upload apps which support iPad-1 (which is stuck with iOS 5.1).

What happens when I try using Xcode 6.4 to submit, is one of the two:

- If I include the standard architectures (both 32 and 64 bits), I'm getting an error saying that apps with 64-bits can't set their target to iOS 5.1.
- If I remove the 64-bits support, I'm getting an error saying that Apple do not allow apps without 64-bits binary.

I was trying to search the internet but didn't find much info. Any idea please?

EDIT

I was trying to use the standalone app loader but it didn't change anything because the validate is done by the remote server. For the second option above, I was getting this:

> ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. Beginning on February 1,
>   2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit
>   support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app
>   updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable
>   64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build
>   setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both
>   32-bit and 64-bit code."

### ANSWER

I got an answer at the developer forums of Apple, so copying here:

Although not in the drop-down box of the deployment targets of Xcode, we need to set the deployment target to be **5.1.1** in order to allow installation on iPad-1 devices.

This is because 5.1.1 is compatible with iPad-1, and is capable of reading dual-architecture binaries.

One thing to consider is that it will not be possible to use TestFlight for testing on these devices, because TestFlight is only compatible with iOS 8 and up. But testing can be taken in other means, like direct-install from Xcode.

Comment: "new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK" That's pretty clear, isn't it? What's the question?

Comment: When 64 bits is included, I cannot set the iOS Deployment Target to 5.1, meaning it will not be compatible with iPad-1.

Comment: You probably need to distribute this outside of the app store.

Comment: "When 64 bits is included, I cannot set the iOS Deployment Target to 5.1, meaning it will not be compatible with iPad-1." Correct. I repeat: what's the question?

Comment: The question is in the title. How can I submit an app which is compatible with iPad-1?

Comment: I think matt is trying to say that you can't, per the evidence you've collected. It might be worth looking up whether you can just substitute the deployment target in the info.plist after build and resign. Unlikely but possibly worth a go.